# How can I access that array of indexes in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int arr[10][2];

int main(){
    memset(arr,-1,sizeof(arr));
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout<<arr[i][i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

```
result = -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0
```

I declared an array of size 2 * 10 as a global variable and initialized it to -1 using the memset function.
However, how did this result come out when I approached the index like arr[i][i] while using the for statement?

Question.

1. How can there be values of arr[3][3], arr[4][4]... that are not declared?
2. Why are the values of arr[7][7], arr[8][8], arr[9][9] different from the previous values?

Thank you.

Comment: Reading outside of array bounds causes undefined behavior: anything can happen, including random values. Some compilers can try to check array bounds for you, if you configure them to do so.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Don't do it even for small examples.

Comment: Also prefer `std::fill` to `memset` for anything other than arrays of bytes. It works in this case, but if you select any value other than -1 or 0, it will do a wrong thing.

Comment: Also, you say that you "declared an array of size 2 * 10" which is wrong. First you *defined* an array. And you defined an array of **`10`** elements. Each element in `arr` is in turn an array of two elements. Also note that `memset` works on a byte-level, it sets all *bytes* to the byte value corresponding to `-1`. Basically only `-1` and `0` will work as expected when using `memset`, anything else will most likely give you unexpected results.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A definition also counts as a declaration. It's a less specific wording, but not wrong. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has **undefined behavior** because you're accessing elements outside the bounds of the array `arr`.

When you wrote:

```
int arr[10][2]; //arr is a 2D array
```

The above statement **defines** a 2D array. This means, `arr` has `10` elements and each of those `10` elements are themselves an array of `2` `int` elements.

This also means that you can only access(safely) the elements:

```
arr[0][0]   arr[0][1]
arr[1][0]   arr[1][1]
arr[2][0]   arr[2][1]
...
...
arr[9][0]   arr[9][1]
```

And if you try to(which you do in your program inside for loop) access any other elements outside the above bounds, you'll get undefined behavior.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB(in this case by making sure that index don't go out of bound). **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

##### Solution 1

One alternative is to use `std::vector` as shown below:

```
//create a 2D vector with 10 rows and 2 columns where each int element has value -1
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(10, std::vector<int>(2, -1));
```

##### Solution 2

You should consider using `std::fill` instead of `memset`:

```
std::fill(*arr, *arr + 10*2, -1);
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple when you clearly

- Array is the object in memory that holds the continuous memory region.
- `2D` array is like `1D` array of 1D arrays, each next row is placed next to the previous one in the memory.
- The name of the array is a reference to the memory region.
- The array type (size of this value) is how the compiler knows how many bytes are taken by each element.
- `cpp` does not check the element size and you are free to use **any index**, this is just to retrieve the unpredictable value that holds next to the array in the memory.

E.g. you have `byte arr[3][2]` - it means that we define an array with `int` elements with `3` rows with `2` columns each.

`sizeof(byte) = 1` - each element in the array takes exactly `1` byte and this is how memory will be allocated.

```
0xA 0xB 0xC 0xD 0xE 0xF 0xAA 0xBB 0xCC
```

*(first 6 bytes are the array; list 3 bytes - are another data in the memory; `arr` is the pointer to the first element)*

`memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr))` - you clear or initialize the array; the memory will be like this:

```
0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xAA 0xBB 0xCC
```

`arr[1][0] = 3` - set an element to `1`; the memory will be like this:

```
0x0 0x0 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xAA 0xBB 0xCC
```

So how would you read this element:

```
arr[1][0];  // 3
*(arr + sizeof(byte) * 2);  // 3
```

As you can see you can easily read smth. behind the array and get unpredictable results:

```
arr[3][0];  // 0xAA
*(arr + sizeof(byte) * 7);  // 0xBB
```

***P.S.** I describe the general answer why you get this result. I do not make a point on another aspect like rotating, because according to CPU addressing rules, where `byte` could take `4` bytes in the memory, but the last `3` bytes will not be used).*